# How do I export a Java application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, export, executable-jar

In Netbeans a simple click to clean/build creates a nice folder called `dist/` in the project workspace and contains a runnable `.jar`, all in the background no repetitive popup menu.

Is there some sort of setting in Eclipse to make this same process faster and easier, even a hotkey to direct export using previously set settings would work?

Comment: Have a look at the ant builder support. Just a very small build script and you won't even need a button to click on - it will create the executable jar each time you save a java source file ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's not particularly hard in eclipse.

1. Right click on the project name and select export.
2. Open the Java section and select "Runnable Jar File", click "Next"
3. Fill out the supplied form with the appropriate options.

That's about it.

Comment: That's what I thought, there is no one button solution. that's fine, thanks.